# What does the notation $A:B$ means for matrices $A$ and $B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

What does the notation $A:B$ means for matrices $A$ and $B$? I saw this is an equation derived from the Navier-Stokes equation. For example,

\begin{equation*}
\int_{\Omega}\nabla(u):\nabla(v)dx
\end{equation*}

for vector fields $v$ and $u$.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to provide a link to where you saw it?  A bit more context could help a great deal in identifying the meaning.  (It is certainly not something I've seen used with matrices before)

Comment: My professor uses it to denote component wise product of two mateix and then take summation  in a PDE course.

Comment: It usually means tensor product.  For matrices that would be
$\sum_{ij} A_{ij} B_{ij}$.
For your particular example
$\int_\Omega \nabla u : \nabla v = \int_\Omega \nabla_i u_j : \nabla_i v_j = \int_\Omega \Delta (u \cdot v)$

Comment: The latter equality is wrong, since each $\nabla$ acts on $u$ and $v$ separately. That could not be simplified further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a **double-dot product**, which unfortunately is used in two different conventions:

$$A:B=\sum_i\sum_j(a_i\cdot d_j)(b_i\cdot c_j)$$
$$A:B=\sum_i\sum_j(a_i\cdot c_j)(b_i\cdot d_j)$$
where $A=\sum_i a_ib_i$ and $B=\sum_i c_id_i$ are two [general dyadics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadics).

---

In line with `uranix`'s comment, if you let $A=\nabla u$ and $B=\nabla v$, you get $A:B=\Delta(u\cdot v)$, in the second convention at least.