# What does this symbol mean here in this context?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, notation

The colon ("$:$" sign) - I am seeing this a lot in Chapter 8 of PDE Evans, like this (page 497 of the 2nd edition):

> **THEOREM 6** (Pressure as Lagrange multiplier)**.** *There exists a scalar function $p \in L^2_{\text{loc}}(U)$ such that*
>   $$\int_U D\mathbf{u} : D\mathbf{v} \, dx = \int_U p \operatorname{div}\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{f}\cdot\mathbf{v}$$ *for all $\mathbf{v} \in H^1(U;\mathbb{R}^3)$ with compact support within $U$.*

Here's another example that uses the colon (page 496 of the 2nd edition):

> **THEOREM 5** (Euler-Lagrange equation for harmonic maps)**.** *Let $\mathbf{u} \in \mathcal{A}$ satisfy* 
>   $$\int_U D\mathbf{u} : D\mathbf{v} \, dx = \int_U p |D\mathbf{u}|^2\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v} \, dx$$ *for eacg $\mathbf{v} \in H^1_0(U;\mathbb{R}^m) \cap L^\infty(U;\mathbb{R}^m)$.*

Comment: A double dot product? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadics#Double-dot_product

Comment: Since $D\mathbf{u}=(Du^1,\ldots,Du^m)$ and $D\mathbf{v}=(Dv^1,\ldots,Dv^m)$ are vectors, why must we take a double dot product $D\mathbf{u} : D\mathbf{v}$? What would go wrong with the traditional singular dot product $D\mathbf{u} \cdot D\mathbf{v}$?

Comment: It's simplest to think of it as entrywise multiplication. One place this would come up is in non-divergence form elliptic operators, where you have a matrix which is entrywise multiplied with the Hessian. A more basic place might be when you try to simplify $\nabla(sv)$ for a scalar field $s$ and vector field $v$ (the result being a matrix field).

Comment: If this is thought as multiplication of the matrix entries as you say, can this be applied to showing that $D\mathbf{u} : D((\mathbf{u}\cdot \mathbf{v})\mathbf{u})=|D\mathbf{u}|^2(\mathbf{u}\cdot \mathbf{v})$, given $(D\mathbf{u})^T\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{0}$?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1270101/what-does-the-notation-ab-means-for-matrices-a-and-b/1270131)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}:\mathbb R^3\supset U\rightarrow \mathbb R^3$, so that $D\mathbf{u},D\mathbf{v}$ are $3\times 3$ matrices. The $:$ here is a matrix inner product defined by $A:B\;:=\mathrm{\mathop{tr}}\,(A^\top B)$ (see also Ciarlet's Mathematical Elasticity, vol. 1, p.xxxi).